# sbt: how to merge multiple jars

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

Is there a way to use sbt to just merge (assembly) multiple jars in one jar.

Let say I have:

- src (empty)
- lib/lib1.jar
- lib/lib2.jar

and I want:

- target/all.jar

Maybe there are some other tools to make that for example using zip to aggregate archives but I think sbt does some useful checks during assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SBT has an assembly plugin:

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

You should be able to add your static lib/ jars as dependencies then the assembly plugin can wrap it all up into one jar.